# IF| ELSE condition to check if Oracle database query output shows any result or NULL

Tags: shell-script, scripting, oracle-database

I am finding it hard to write an if|else statement for the below condition.
What I am doing is I have an Oracle database where I am running the below query and it returns output in rows (it can show records or it can return NULL values), what I want is if the row returned as output then it should execute couple of commands and if no rows are returned then it should execute second set of commands.

Example 1 -- it shows the output.

```
SQL> select value from v$parameter where name='spfile';
VALUE
---------------
+DATA_01/TESTDB/spfileTESTDB.ora
```

Example 2 -- In some cases it can return no rows.

```
SQL> select value from v$parameter where name='spfile';
VALUE
--------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do something like this:

```
db_connect="user/pass@db"

output=$(
    sqlplus -s "$db_connect" <<'END' | sed '/^$/d'
        set heading off
        select value from v$parameter where name='spfile';
END
)
```

The `-s` option and `set heading off` sqlplus command are meant to minimize extraneous output. `sed '/^$/d'` is to delete empty lines. The result in `$output` should either be an empty string (for null result) or the line(s) of query output.

Note that the `END` heredoc terminator must not have any other characters on that line. That's why it's not indented like the other lines.

Then you can do:

```
if [[ -n "$output" ]]; then
    stuff if there is output
else
    stuff if there is null output
fi
```

Comment: Thank you Glen, It really solved out my problem. Really appreciate your help on this. Just wanted to understand what if [[ -n "$ouput"]] would do here.

Comment: It's a test for "non-empty". See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html